# New Django South migration breaks an earlier one

Tags: django, unit-testing, migration, django-south

## A. Summary:

*After successfully running a new migration (adds a new column to an existing table), an earlier migration that operates on the same table (`0010`) fails with:*

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_ymc_platform" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_ymc_platform', or 'no' to cancel:
```

*And when I respond with `yes`:*

```
Error in migration: ymc:0010_auto__add_field_user_registered_at
DatabaseError: column users.publisher_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...dress", "users"."gender", "users"."developer_id", "users"."publisher_id...
                                                             ^
```

## B. Details:

### 1. How are these migrations run?

They are run by Django's unit tests. [As you know, South runs "every migration every time you run your tests."](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/unittests.html)

### 2. Migration History

I have (among others) three tables: `users`, `games` and `publishers`. Up until migration `0025`, they had nothing to do with one another. In migration `0025`, I add a foreign key where `users.publisher_id` and `games.publisher_id` reference `publishers`.

When I created and ran `0025`, I was at `0024` and everything migrated successfully. Then I ran my unit tests and got the prompt and error message described above. So `0025`-->`0024` works, but `0009`-->`0010` fails.

My current migration history is like this:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate ymc --list

 ymc
  (*) 0001_initial
   ...
  (*) 0004_auto__add_field_user_gender
   ...
  (*) 0010_auto__add_field_user_registered_at
   ...
  (*) 0025_auto__add_field_user_publisher__add_field_game_publisher
```

*`0004` is included as a demonstration that South can run migrations on the `users` table without choking. Perhaps something is special about `0010`.*

### 2. What does your model code for that new column look like?

I added `publisher_id` columns to both `users` and `games` like so:

```
# Same for both 'users' and 'games'
publisher = models.ForeignKey('ymc.Publisher', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

### 3. What code did South generate?

Here's the existing migration that's started failing:

#### `0010_auto__add_field_user_registered_at`:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'User.registered_at'
        db.add_column('users', 'registered_at',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(null=True, blank=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        users = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            user.registered_at = user.joined_at
            user.save()

    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'User.registered_at'
        db.delete_column('users', 'registered_at')


    models = {
        ...
        'ymc.user': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'User', 'db_table': "'users'"},
            'access_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'access_token_expiry': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'developer': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'default': 'None', 'to': "orm['ymc.Developer']", 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'email': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '128'}),
            'facebook_access_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'facebook_id': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'first_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'forgot_password_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'forgot_password_token_expiry': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'games': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'symmetrical': 'False', 'to': "orm['ymc.Game']", 'null': 'True', 'through': "orm['ymc.UsersGames']", 'blank': 'True'}),
            'gender': ('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField', [], {'default': 'None', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'ip_address': ('django.db.models.fields.IPAddressField', [], {'max_length': '15', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'is_admin': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'joined_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'last_login': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'last_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'password': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '128'}),
            'registered_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'salt': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'unique': 'True', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'username': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '128'}),
            'verified_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'})
        },
        ...
    }
```

And here's the new migration that, while successfully applied, causes `0010` to choke.

#### `0025_auto__add_field_user_publisher__add_field_game_publisher`

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Adding field 'User.publisher'
        db.add_column('users', 'publisher',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(default=None, to=orm['ymc.Publisher'], null=True, blank=True),
                      keep_default=False)

        # Adding field 'Game.publisher'
        db.add_column('games', 'publisher',
                      self.gf('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey')(default=None, to=orm['ymc.Publisher'], null=True, blank=True),
                      keep_default=False)


    def backwards(self, orm):
        # Deleting field 'User.publisher'
        db.delete_column('users', 'publisher_id')

        # Deleting field 'Game.publisher'
        db.delete_column('games', 'publisher_id')


    models = {
        ...
        'ymc.user': {
            'Meta': {'object_name': 'User', 'db_table': "'users'"},
            'access_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'access_token_expiry': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'developer': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'default': 'None', 'to': "orm['ymc.Developer']", 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'email': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '128'}),
            'facebook_access_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'facebook_id': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'first_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'forgot_password_token': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '255', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'forgot_password_token_expiry': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'games': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'symmetrical': 'False', 'to': "orm['ymc.Game']", 'null': 'True', 'through': "orm['ymc.UsersGames']", 'blank': 'True'}),
            'gender': ('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField', [], {'default': 'None', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
            'ip_address': ('django.db.models.fields.IPAddressField', [], {'max_length': '15', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'is_admin': ('django.db.models.fields.BooleanField', [], {'default': 'False'}),
            'joined_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'last_login': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'last_name': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'password': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'unique': 'True', 'max_length': '128'}),
            'publisher': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'default': 'None', 'to': "orm['ymc.Publisher']", 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'registered_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'salt': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128', 'unique': 'True', 'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
            'username': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'max_length': '128'}),
            'verified_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'null': 'True', 'blank': 'True'})
        },

        ...
    }
```

### 4. What's the output if you run the tests with `--verbose=3`?

This:

```
 ...
 > ymc:0010_auto__add_field_user_registered_at
   = ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "registered_at" timestamp with time zone NULL; []
   = ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "registered_at" TYPE timestamp with time zone, ALTER COLUMN "registered_at" DROP NOT NULL, ALTER COLUMN "registered_at" DROP DEFAULT; []
Error in migration: ymc:0010_auto__add_field_user_registered_at
 - Sending post_syncdb signal for ymc: ['Game', 'UsersGames', 'User', 'Developer']
DatabaseError: column users.publisher_id does not exist    
LINE 1: ...dress", "users"."gender", "users"."developer_id", "users"."p...
```

### 5. What have you tried?

- Rolling everything back and trying again (exact same results).
- Wishing really hard that this is a dream.
- Man... other than that, not much. I'm super confused. I don't even
  understand where this error message is being generated:

  ```
   LINE 1: ...dress", "users"."gender", "users"."developer_id", "users"."p...
                                                                ^ Like,
  ```

  `LINE 1:` of what, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following code in migration `0010`:

```
from ymc.model.users import User
...
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        user.registered_at = user.joined_at
        user.save()
```

I think this must have been added by the guy who built the system and is no longer here. He's smart and awesome, but nobody's perfect. [According to the South docs on data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html), you need to use `orm.YourModel`, otherwise the current schema is used. That's why South/the database was seeing the new `publisher_id` column.

The block should have been:

```
users = orm.User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    user.registered_at = user.joined_at
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the complete migration files generated by south?

**EDIT:**

Migrations seems to be correct, just wanted to see if someone fiddled with it. But sometimes you gotta have fiddle with the things around to get them straight. I would suggest you to move the code related to model data, i.e.

```
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    user.registered_at = user.joined_at
    user.save()
```

into separate migration. To create a blank migration, a migration file w/o any code in it's `forward` & `backward` methods, use `python manage.py datamigration app_name file_name` and add above code in forward method.

I hope this works for you..

Comment: The two relevant migrations (`0010`, `0025`) are pretty much complete. I added the `users` hash in `models = {...}` anyway, in case it helps. I think posting either more migrations or more code in the existing ones will be of limited helpfulness, unwieldy and potentially a security problem for my company.

Comment: Thanks Arpit. You're right that organizationally, the code should be in a data-specific migration. That alone won't fix the problem however. My solution below (using `orm`) will.